# stop iOS contact importing contact info from mail footers

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email, contacts, gmail

I recently changed from using the gmail app to the native iOS mail app on my iphone.

Now when i search for a contact in the address book to make a phone call it seems to have pulled in a load of contact info from peoples email footers, i have some email accounts for work that i dont want to clutter up my contact book, is it possible to only set the 'search emails for contact info' setting to only apply to select email accounts ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not available per-account, but the setting is adjusted in iOS 10 in Settings > Contacts. At the bottom of the list is a toggle for **Contacts Found in Apps** and that's what controls this pseudo-importing.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they are able to be separated by turning off certain groups of people from different accounts. For example, see pic below. [image]